# Openstack Cinder Unable to update attachment Invalid volume duplicate connectors detected on volume

Tags: openstack, cinder

Sometimes when Compute Server is rebooted suddenly or in another similar situation, we want to `evacuate` instances to another host we get this error from Cinder.

Our Cinder's backed is Ceph

```
{'code': 400, 'created': '2022-09-26T15:34:22Z', 'message': 'Unable to update attachment.(Invalid volume: duplicate connectors detected on volume ....). (HTTP 500) (Request-ID:req-c....)'}
```

I want to migrate or evacuate the instance but we get this error. How can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is a safeguard against data corruption by mounting the same volume in 2 instances, as explained here:

https://opendev.org/openstack/cinder/commit/eadff0df7efbe662bf107f77e1b2ac96c912e4e0

> If multiple attachments are requested simultaneously, a volume can be
> attached to an instance more than once.
>
> This fixes this problem by detecting that a race has occurred in
> _attachment_reserve, and backing out one of the invalid attachment records.
>
> This means that if the attachment API is called repeatedly and quickly
> for the same volume, some requests may fail, but this is much better
> than incorrectly creating multiple attachments.

I would try to dettach and re-attach the volume to the server to workaround this (`openstack server remove volume` and `openstack server remove volume`)

Comment: The problem is here exactly when Compute failed and is not stable we are not able to use these commands. Volume is stuck in this state.

Comment: when you do openstack volume show VOLUME_ID in which state you see the volume?

Comment: in-use; I change it manually to available but don't see the effect on evac. I'm not able to remove volume from the server/instance and also evacuate or migrate the server/instance.

Comment: Try to provide logs from cinder after running cinder reset-state --state available --attach-status detached VOLUME_ID